# Why won't JQVmap appear online

Tags: jqvmap

I have a jqvmap map on my homepage but I don't know why the map does not show online.
I have all the correct files and I am linking them correctly.
The map should show underneath the dropdown list and before the shadow image.

Here is my website http://www.wearemovingto.com

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I look at the source of your site and click on the links below, I get error 404 pages. So I guess that the relative path "js/" you use is incorrect.

```
<script src="js/jquery.vmap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.vmap.world.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.vmap.sampledata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jqvmap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot, In the Godaddy plesk I had all my JS files in the JQVmap folder.

Comment: It happens more often than you might think :)